# My team's robot keeps spinning for a random amount of time and we don't know why

Tags: java, methods, robotics

We are using the modern robotics gyro.
We program in java.
We are using the base code provided by FTC for the First Tech Challenge.
Here is our gyro code as well as the turning code including the code that is supposed to stop the robot.

gyro = hardwareMap.get(ModernRoboticsI2cGyro.class, "gyro");

ModernRoboticsI2cGyro gyro;

private static final double GYRO_TOLERANCE = 4.00; // degrees
  private static final long GYRO_DELAY = 10; //ms

```
public void turn(double angle, double power)
{

    Hw.frontLeftDrive.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_USING_ENCODER);
    Hw.frontRightDrive.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_USING_ENCODER);
    Hw.backLeftDrive.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_USING_ENCODER);
    Hw.backRightDrive.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_USING_ENCODER);

    // Sets angle above 0 and below 360 to prevent errors when plugging values in.
    angle = angle % 360;
    if(angle == 0 || power == 0) // if someone plugs in 0 for power or the angle, it just stops the statement and continues
        return;
    power = Math.abs(power);
    if(power > 0.5) power = 0.5; // and this sets power to half power if anyone plugs in a higher value than half

    if(Math.abs(angle) > 180.0) power = -power; //sets power sign (+ or -) to sign of angle

    //gets current angle and adds desired change to it
    float currentAngle = Hw.gyro.getHeading();
    float targetAngle = (float) (currentAngle + angle);


    // give robot some boundaries when checking gyro to prevent infinite checking of accuracy
    double tolerance = GYRO_TOLERANCE * Math.abs(power);
    long compensatedDelay = (long)(GYRO_DELAY / Math.abs(power));

    //make sure angle is over 0 or under 361
    if (targetAngle > 360)
        targetAngle -= 360;
    else if (targetAngle < 0)
        targetAngle += 360;

    double maxLimit = targetAngle + tolerance;
    double minLimit = targetAngle - tolerance;

    //set power states of motors
    Hw.frontLeftDrive.setPower(power);
    Hw.frontRightDrive.setPower(-power);
    Hw.backLeftDrive.setPower(power);
    Hw.backRightDrive.setPower(-power);

    // repeatedly check position for best accuracy until it falls into the set boundaries
    double current = Hw.gyro.getHeading();
    **while(current > maxLimit || current < minLimit){
        sleep(compensatedDelay);
        current = Hw.gyro.getHeading();
    }**
    //stops motors
    Hw.frontLeftDrive.setPower(0);
    Hw.frontRightDrive.setPower(0);
    Hw.backLeftDrive.setPower(0);
    Hw.backRightDrive.setPower(0);
}
```

Comment: Side note: consider using `{` and `}` around all your blocks as it will make life easier in the long run.

Comment: hmm either it hops over the tolerance(during sleep) or adding tollerance lead you out of the gyro.getHeading() range(probably both). I see other parts that look confusing. Why don't adjust in the while the power. So you need some initial power(depending on the angle) and the closer you get to target, the slower you turn

Comment: as for passing the heading, I have tested this without the tolerance and it just spins indefinitely.  as for the slow down, ill try putting it at the slowest speed possible before i try that.  Ill do that now, thank you in advance

Comment: also decide for one coordinate system an transform cleanly.(where is 0°?) the startingAngle may be a good choice for 0. (transforming the current into that coordinatesystem: adding delta and normalizing to the range -180 .. 180) so targetAngle is in the range -180° and + 180° which makes comparison easier/posible.

Comment: Are you filtering the bias of the gyro before starting the main execution?